# Filter posts by custom field (Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields and have been following along with this tutorial on [Creating a WP archive with Custom Field Filter](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/tutorials/creating-wp-archive-custom-field-filter/). In their example, they're using Radio Button Field; I would like to use the Checkbox Field for a custom post type called 'book', as some of my books have more than one 'book_type' associated with them.

**Field name:** book_type

**Field type**: Checkbox Field

**Choices:** men, women, children, accessories

My `functions.php` page looks like this:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}

$book_format = $query->get('meta_query');
    if( !empty($_GET['book_type']) ) {
        $book_format[] = array(
            'key'       => 'type',
            'value'     => $_GET['book_type'],
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',
        );
    }

$query->set('meta_query', $book_format);
return;
}
```

Now, when I manually add my 'book_type' to my url like this:

```
dev.com/books?=men
```

it successfully shows all books related to men. But when I add the '|' seperator, as you do with an array, I get a blank page.

```
dev.com/books?=men|women|accessories
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the link you give use checkbox in the code snippet

Comment: No, that's a checkbox for the page template. To check/uncheck multiple choices on the front-end. I'm trying to use a Checkbox Field when they're using a Radio Field to retrieve the values.

Comment: I've edited my original question above, to help explain the issue a little further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're receiving an array, your `meta_query` is going to change. `LIKE` will no longer be valid, you'd need to do an `IN` comparison at that point.

Also I'm not entirely convinced you're correctly passing a [`$_GET` array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833398/1238781)

Comment: I've tried an `IN` comparison, but no results are shown. I just get a blank page.

Comment: If you get a blank page, you should check your logs for the error report... You _do_ have debugging enabled, right? Also, updated answer.

Comment: I have debugging enabled. Not getting an error on the "?books=men" page, but am getting an "Undefined index" error in relation to the `$_GET` param I'm using on my archive page template.

Comment: I've been trying to work out how to print that `$_GET` array, so I can check it. Can I not do it in Chrome's Console? Sorry for these silly questions, I'm still trying to wrap my head around PHP and this is my first time in the trenches.

Comment: Chrome's console won't help with PHP, only javascript and CSS. Go read your logs, as you don't always get output

Comment: Could you tell me how I'd go about finding my logs? I'm using MAMP and Chrome.

Comment: Just install this, it'll make life easier: http://wordpress.org/plugins/error-log-dashboard-widget/

Comment: Yup! Seems to be a problem with my `$_GET` parameter. "Error: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array". So does that mean my 'type' isn't an array.

Comment: Right. I gave you a link to a method for correctly forming arrays in `$_GET`, above. But the gist is `?arr[]=a&arr[]=b&arr[]=c` etc;